# How to write a code that takes 3 inputs and prints them?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, input, user-input

I apologize if this question is too basic, but i really am stuck here. I want to print 3 numbers which the user will input , but for some reason i can only take them one at a time. Is there a way the user can input all three numbers at once, without the code asking the same question three times?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Input three values: ");

            int[] arr = new int[3];  //this is the array which will store the 3 numbers
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //for loop that iterates three times
            {
                arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //gets user input and converts it to integer

                var value = arr[i]; //input is stored in variable 'value'


                Console.WriteLine("Here are your 3 numbers: " + value);  //output
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have the user enter 3 numbers in one line with some type of delimiter, like space, etc. and split your input string, but in a console app with no gui elements but the console window, i cant think of another way without the loop

Comment: Get the console WriteLine  out of the loop and put all together Console.WriteLine("Here are your 3 numbers: " + string.Join(", ", arr));

Comment: @Jonxag Thank you very much it works now! So the issue was me writing the Console.WriteLine within the for loop?

Comment: Thats it, the message was shown 3 times becouse it was inside the loop, also you were just storing the data into the array and not using it on the WriteLine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

---

The output line is inside the for-loop so it will print again every time you put a number. Also, the input is already stored in your array, and the "value" variable holds only a temporary value which will disappear for every loop of your for-loop and when the loop ends up. You should use a for-loop outside the ones that is in your code, which prints every value without a new line

Your code should look like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input three values: ");

    int[] arr = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    
    Console.Write("Here are your 3 numbers:");
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        Console.Write(" " + arr[i]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

### Tip

---

You can make your code support more than one number and display all of them in a cool way  by treating them as strings.

Something like this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Input your values: ");
        string[] list = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    
    Console.Write($"Here are your {list.Length} numbers:");
    for(int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
            Console.Write(" " + list[i]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the answer i needed, thank you so much for clarifying everything and for the cool method :] i love that!!

Comment: i just run the code but it doesn't seem to be working, it only stores the first number i input and the code ends

Comment: the second one is quite diferent working, write every number separated with a space, like "1 4 31 141 12"